# Wagtail Django-form edit existing object

Tags: django, django-forms, wagtail

I am following the wagtail-form-example on GitHub to implement a Django Form into wagtail. I've got everything working except being able to edit an existing submission.

This is the code I have followed so far
https://github.com/gasman/wagtail-form-example/blob/master/flavours/models.py

I have tried a couple of variants of the below code.

```
def serve(request, id):
   instance = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=id)
   form = MyForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
```

If it helps I'm getting the following message:
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Any help/examples would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing `def serve(self, request):` to `def serve(request, id):` doesn't work that way.

Your second argument `id` now holds the `request` object and not the expected int like the error tells you.

Start by respecting the method arguments `serve(self, request)`. That means you need to query your form in some other way.

Eg: `get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=[some hardcoded id])`

If you want any form to be shown as child of your page, you could use [RoutablePageMixin](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/contrib/routablepage.html#module-wagtail.contrib.routable_page) add an url relative to your page. Eg:

```
@route(r'^(\d+)/$')
def form_view(self, request, form_id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=form_id)
```